Short story about very young aliens (toddlers) invading a starship to play; they like the crew; removed by an adult alien but they want to visit again
Humorous short story written by a woman science fiction writer, I've forgotten who. The little aliens suddenly appear inside a spaceship They have teleported into various parts of the ship from their home place. They only want to play but as toddlers often are, they are unknowingly destructive. The crew are at their wits end trying to keep the ship safe, but at the same time they find the little alien kids enchanting. An adult alien, whom the small aliens call "she", arrives and removes them. The babies plot to return to the ship after "she" goes away again.
Part of the story is told all-in-lower-case alien-baby-babble from the toddler-aliens perspective, but a larger part is told from the perspective of various crew members.
The only phrase of the baby-babble I remember is "human bean" or possibly "yuman bean" or some other variant, but the phrase definitely include "bean".
I'm sorry that I don't remember the period when it was written, I think the '80s, but it could be almost anytime from the '60s onward until about 2010.
